# How to specify the name of a database to get the name of its tables using sql server 2005 syntax

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I need to write a query in SQL Server 2005 to get the name of the tables of a specified 
database name. So I need the syntax to specify the name of the database using SQL Server 2005.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

```
use DatabaseName;

SELECT *
FROM Information_Schema.Tables
```

Or specify the name of the database in your connection string and run

```
SELECT *
FROM Information_Schema.Tables
```

Or use a fully qualified name

```
SELECT *
FROM DatabaseName.Information_Schema.Tables
```

In your case, try this

```
SELECT name As descriptionCommande from YOURDATABASENAME.sys.Views
```

OR

```
USE YOURDATABASENAME
SELECT name As descriptionCommande from sys.Views
```

Comment: @Raj - hope you don't mind, corrected InformationSchema to Information_Schema

Comment: SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_catalog = @databasename and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

Comment: @zapping - the information_schema runs within the context of the current database. It will return the tables for that db only.

Comment: thanks zapping. I execute your query but I didn't receive any data...
To be more descriptive , this is my query :SELECT sys.Views.name As descriptionCommande
FROM sys.Views
I just  need to specify the name of the database in a where clause using vb code 
so I need the syntax of the query to specify the name of the database

Answer (score 1):

If your database is Northwind for example

```
SELECT name FROM Northwind..sysobjects WHERE type='U'
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but this sentence will also return the sysdiagrams table so watch out since  you may not need it. for the rest the query will work.

Comment: it does work 
I need specify the name of the database that i created on the server 
for ex: SELECT sys.Tables.name 
FROM sys.Tables INNER Join sys.sql_modules ON sys.Tables.object_ID = sys.sql_modules.object_id
inner join sys.databases on sys.Tables.object_ID = sys.databases.
where ........... = 'Databasename'

Comment: You want to use the xtype field: "WHERE xtype = 'U'"

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you want to specify the name dynamically, in which case you need to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128)
SET @DatabaseName = 'DatabaseName'

-- Safety check to make sure the database is a valid db name
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name = @DatabaseName)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @nSQL NVARCHAR(200)
  SET @nSQL = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @nSQL
 END
```

Comment: I need to specify the name of the databse in the clause WHERE 
to get the name of its tables in my query

Comment: @CREFLY - you can't specify it in a WHERE clause - there is no central list of tables for all databases. Hence, you have to look in the appropriate database itself. Unless you create a separate job to iterate round each db periodically and pull out a list of tables into somewhere central.